# How to format as quote using Inbox by Gmail?

Tags: inbox-by-gmail

I miss how we could quote in Gmail using the "quote" button with formatting tools.

But it has been removed in Inbox by Gmail, is there a new way that I didn't see to quote now?

Comment: It's seriously most frustrating thing for me and I switch all the time to Gmail to start quote...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because Inbox by Gmail was retired in April, 2019.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

One solution is to write your quotes using [Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/), then use the [Markdown Here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/markdown-here/elifhakcjgalahccnjkneoccemfahfoa?hl=en) Chrome extension to convert it to HTML.

[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: Jesus. This extension wants permission to "read and change all your data on the websites you visit." Looks great, but nope.

Comment: @mlissner I'm guessing it needs that in order to be able to do direct DOM manipulation for replacing the Markdown with HTML. It's an open source project, meaning it's possible to look at the source to ensure there isn't anything nefarious going on. See: https://github.com/adam-p/markdown-here

Comment: There's absolutely no guarantee that the code on Github is being deployed to the chrome store. Maybe this is normal for extensions, but it seems crazy to me.

Answer (score 9):

Inbox by Gmail is a new app, so it doesn't have features removed yet, instead it doesn't have yet some expected features as a "quote" button.

From [An inbox that works for you - Official Gmail Blog](http://gmailblog.blogspot.mx/2014/10/an-inbox-that-works-for-you.html)

> When you start using Inbox, you’ll quickly see that it doesn’t feel
>   the same as Gmail—and that’s the point. Gmail’s still there for you,
>   but Inbox is something new. It’s a better way to get back to what
>   matters, and we can’t wait to share it with you.

Comment: It has all the other formatting options dammit. Get on it, Google!

Comment: Quoting is a key part of email. The fact they still don't have it a year into Inbox is ridiculous.

Comment: @aendrew: Please send your feedback to Google.

Answer (score 1):

Super hacky, but if you don't want to install a plugin you can do it by first typing your email into an online markdown editor like this one -> https://dillinger.io (Any with an HTML preview will do) Copy the preview and paste it into your gmail / inbox composer.

As a side note, I found it's important to capture the whole preview, so it's better if you have some "padding" text to make it easier to copy the whole quote block with the HTML start code for instance:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Recently I have been using an extension for Inbox call [MixMax](https://mixmax.com/tracking-templates-google-inbox?ref=producthunt), which lets you:

- Format the text
- and place the signature above any quoted text.